# R TTR package EMA function Ratio field

Tags: r

TTR package EMA function. What does ratio do?

Exmple code:

```
library("TTR")
a <- 1:5
EMA(a,n=1)
```

Result
1 2 3 4 5

```
EMA(a,n=1,ratio=1/3)
```

Result
1.000 1.3333 1.8888 2.5926 3.3951

I've looked at EMA function calculation on google and nowehere can I find a ratio field.

I have seen the monster function for EMA and it's overkill. So how does this calc work using ratio in understandable language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All exponential moving averages use a ratio.  The ratio is alpha in [this Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average).  If you don't supply a ratio in the call to `TTR::EMA`, it assumes you want `ratio = 2/(n+1)` (the standard in technical analysis). If you don't specify a ratio and `wiler=TRUE`, then `ratio=1/n` (Welles Wilder's calculation).

Comment: what is `n` the number of observations?